# Refresh page but keep checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I know I am a straight noob and I have tried a lot of different ways to get this jsfiddle to work like I want it to. But still no luck.

Im linking to the version where the first checkbox keeps its

http://jsfiddle.net/Acree/wv2us4od/14/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yolo">
<input type="checkbox" id="yolo2">
<input type="checkbox" id="yolo3">


$(function(){
var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
$('#yolo').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('#yolo').on('change', function() {
localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Basically I need all the checkboxes to save independently of each other.
The context is so a user could check off things they can do and it will be there when they come back to the site.
http://pk-unity.com/tricks/index2.html

Comment: Rather refreshing the whole page you can reload/refresh the required portion  of the page with jquery ajax. Then you will be and I can give answer if you follow methodology.

Comment: The idea is to be able to come back a week later and it still be checked.
So you could close down the page, and then come back and its still checked.

Comment: You can use cookies. Or localStorage. Or a database...

Comment: Which programming language you are using? Also will come back later after week in the same computer or different computer?

Comment: Im trying to use localStorage above. How do I expand my JS to include multiple checkboxes? As in check if checkboxes are being checked and keeping that state.

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wv2us4od/16/)

```
if(localStorage.length > 0)
{
    $.each(localStorage,function(index,item)
    {
        if( $("#"+index)[0] )
        { 
            if(item == "true")
                $("#"+index).attr("checked","checked");
        }
    });
}
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() 
{
    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"),($(this).is(":checked") ? true : false));
});
```